# Javascript: closing a popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

I am a JS noob, so please excuse me if this question is too "noobish".

Note: the function is long, but just scroll down till you see //******************* as that's the important part.

My function:

```
function ShowWindowN(userId,url,width,height,courseId) {
  var iev=getIEVer();
  if(iev>=6&&iev<8){
    width+=16*1;
  }
  var w=screen.availWidth<width?screen.availWidth:width;
  var csCookie=readCookie('course_settings_'+userId);
  var found=false;
  if(csCookie!=null){
    csCookie=eval('({'+csCookie.replace(/&/g,',').replace(/=/g,':')+'})');
    if(csCookie[courseId]!=null){
      height+=1*csCookie[courseId].height;
      found=true;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
    var plCookie=readCookie('player_settings_'+userId);
    if(plCookie!=null){
      plCookie=eval('({'+plCookie.replace(/&/g,',').replace(/=/g,':')+'})');
      height+=1*plCookie.window_extra_height;
    }else{
      height+=16;
    }
  }
  var h=screen.availHeight<height?screen.availHeight:height;
  var left = (screen.availWidth/2)-(w/2);
  //************
  objMovieWindow=window.open(url, "movieWindow", "width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", top=0, left="+left+", status=false, toolbar=false, menubar=false, location=false, directories=false, scrollbars=1, resizable=1"); 
  objMovieWindow.focus();
  //alert(objMovieWindow.name);
};
```

If you look at the alert() on the 2nd last line, that does not work, it gives me a "permissions denied" error. I also have a function that says "close_me()" with just this:

```
objMovieWindow.close();
```

But that does not work and gives me an "undefined" error. Basically, I load the page, and click a link to launch the popup, then the parent page reloads, and by clicking a link on the parent page I want to close the popup.

Please tell me how I can close the damn popup window?

Comment: Your code works for me. So the issue is not in the code per se.

Comment: Could it be Firefox? I am on FF 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reload the page you are losing the reference to `objMovieWindow`, so you won't be able to call `objMovieWindow.close()`. You'll have to avoid reloading the page if you want to close the window.

**UPDATE**

One work around would be to call `window.open()` again with the same name, and call `close()` on the reference returned from that.

Comment: How can I save that reference then? Because I have no choice, the page MUST reload...

Comment: You could just open it again (with the same exact name), then call close on it.

Comment: Nope, have to close the window that I opened the first time... possible? No way to save the reference and then call it again?

Comment: If you `open()` the window again with the same name it **won't** open a new window, but instead use the same one as before and return the same reference. Give it a shot.

Comment: And no, there's no way to save the reference.

Comment: YESSSS! You da man, dude! After hours of searching where I screwed up you gave me the answer! Thanks!